# External javascript file in html not working

Tags: javascript, html

first post..
trying javascript for first time.
i am following a book , created two files in the same directory
test_js.html
helloWorld.js

Contents of both are below:
test_js.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title> First Javascript page </title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="helloWorld.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

helloWorld.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("hello");
</script>
```

I dont see any alert when i load the html page.
However if i embed the same alert("hello") in the html page, i am seeing the alert being displayed.

Tried this on chrome and firefox (both latest) with same result.
Following googled examples is not showing any error in any of the files.

Please help.

Comment: you don't use `script` tags inside a javascript file - because it's a javascript file, not a HTML file

Answer (score 4):

remove script tags from helloWorld.js

just

```
alert("hello");
```

Comment: Thank you all. Its working now after removing the <script tag from the external javascript file. Strange that there are many examples out on the internet which specify the script tag for the external javascript file.